# Cannot invoke 'SaveUserData' with an argument list of type '(Dictionary<String, Int>)'

Tags: swift, invoke

When I'm trying to save data to file, this Error came out.
Please  help me, thanks!

```
var UserData:Dictionary<String,Int> = ["Level":1,"energy": 20,"EXP":0]
func SaveUserData (UserData :Dictionary<String,Int>){...} 
SaveAndReadUserData.SaveUserData(UserData) // The Error came out from here
```

Comment: Please post more code. I assume that func SaveUserData is a method of the struct or class (instance?) named SaveAndReadUserData. Is it? Is there another method named SaveUserData() in the class/instance SaveAndReadUserData?

Comment: Thank you, I found the problem, as you say,  there is another name for the method.     var SaveAndReadData = SaveAndReadUserData()              I should use SaveAndReadData or not  SaveAndReadUserData.    Thank you very much!

Comment: You should name your variable and method with first character is lowercase.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! (^_^)